# socket.io broadcast to room that have id 1>

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I make `nodejs` applications using sockets,
The user then conect with socket in the room Join Its own id, example ROOM 1 ROOM 2 Up room 100

I Want To Broadcast to rooms that have  ROOMS  id 10 ROOMS to 100,
how `socket.io` handle

Comment: why every connected user should have a different room?

Comment: room have different data